# url.py settings.py with external storage with dropbox

Tags: django, django-urls, dropbox-api, django-settings

I would like to use dropbox as external storage. I have been working on this for a week and I think identified the problem.

url.py has:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Settings.py contains :

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage"
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = #mytoken
```

I obtain the error:

```
ApiError('d5b8d0d14e950566defb5ca736ebda9a', GetTemporaryLinkError('path', LookupError('not_found', None)))
```

because it can't find the static there:

```
<img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" height = 300></img>
```

How do I configure STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL (and MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_URL) in order to link to dropbox url? I'm expecting something like :
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a model like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
```

access the photo using `MyModel.photo` because it contains a URL that points to the photo in dropbox.